# WP8 change color of a Single application bar button

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, application-bar

I've been reading through a few posts, and from as far as I can tell, it **is** possible to change to color of the entire application bar so it doesn't use the default light/dark themes.

However, I'm writing an app where it would be convenient for the color of a single app bar button to change, i.e. On press, `colour = default magenta`, and it remains like this untill it has been clicked again.

I have a feeling that this isn't possible, and I'll have to rely on using various images to describe what's going on.

So I'm wondering if there is a solution that doesn't involve doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

afaik, IconUri is your only way of doing it. The background/foreground color of the whole app bar can be changed as a whole, not the individual buttons.

p.s. it is not recommended to change the colors of app bar buttons without a compelling reason. (for UI design guidelines, UX, power consumption reasons etc.)